# Blue screen crash

Tags: bsod, crash

What is definitive way to identify that blue screen crash is caused by faulty hardware not device driver? How to distinguish blue screen crashes caused by faulty hardware from device drivers and unsigned drivers?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, really, in most cases.

Troubleshooting is nearly always about a progression from the most likely to the less likely possible causes, balanced with a measurement of the ease of resolution.

If something is only moderately likely, but will take only a moment to check and probably won't require a reboot to fix, you do that first.

When troubleshooting a specific BSOD, you start with what information you can know:

- Error logs.
- Messages on the screen during the event.
- What applications (and what types of applications) were running at the time.
- Historical error information.
- Physical observations of the event.

And from that you build a scenario with more and less likely possible causes. Then you work your way through them.

Sometimes something stands out as being worth checking into at the beginning, even though it is likely to be a bigger, more complicated and/or expensive problem.

For instance, if you heard a grinding noise coming from inside the computer case immediately prior to or during the BSOD event, then you'd open that case right up and check it out first thing.

But, because it is easier and cheaper to try reinstalling drivers, updating software, and things like that, you generally start with these steps before proceeding to hardware testing and replacement.

Also, if you have a spare comparable piece of hardware available that you can swap in, that makes it easier to test a possible hardware fault, and so this step could move up the troubleshooting ladder moreso than if you didn't have any spare computer parts lying around.

In other words: There isn't normally a way to say with 100% certainty right at the beginning that a problem is hardware-caused unless there is some factor pointing solidly towards that fact.